# Drupal webform location?

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I am working on adding content to an existing site, and I can't figure out how to connect different web forms to different specific pages.

example: http://network.awcbn.com/3blindmicewindowcoverings
I need to replicate this page for other companies listed on the same site. But each webform will be on a different "basic page" and will be sent to a different email address.

I know virtually nothing about coding, and I'm wondering if this can just be done in the webform settings or drupal admin settings. without having to "pop open the hood" and mess with the code?

Basically I just don't know how to place a specific webform on a specific page. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

There's a great module for that called webform:

http://drupal.org/project/webform

When you create a node of type webform, there's a subtab under edit for configuring the fields, email messages, etc.  Documentation is here:

http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/webform